# Need to scan a directory and delete only specific type of file

Tags: php, html

I need to have a php script that allows me to scan a directory and then, delete the files from it, my code works just fine, it lists all I need but, my problem is that I need to delete only a specific file from that directory and this script scans everything, in this case i am trying to delete only the .sql files created. However this script lists all types of files.

I leave my code below:

```
    <?php
$fid= $_POST['fid'];
if (("submit")&&($fid != "")) {
foreach($fid as $rfn) {
$remove = "$dire/$rfn";
unlink($remove);
}
}
$handle=opendir($dire);
while (($file = readdir($handle))!== false){
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
$size = filesize("$dire/$file");
$list .= '<table class="table table-bordered table-dark table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
$list .= '<tbody>';
$list .= '<tr style="text-transform:uppercase;">';
$list .= '<td><small>'.$file.'</small></td>';
$list .= '<td align="center"><small><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="fid[]" value="'.$file.'"></small></td>';
$list .= '</tr>';
$list .= '</tbody>';
$list .= '</table>';
}
}
closedir($handle);
echo $list;
?>
```

As you can see, this code works just fine, not pretty I know but I need to have a way to show only my SQL files and not the other types of files.

Comment: Just check file extension and do what you want with that - `$extension  = pathinfo("$dire/$file", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Have you considered using GLOB() and scan only sql files? $files = GLOB($dire . '/*{.sql}', GLOB_BRACE);

Comment: @Autista_z yes, but by any chance can you place me an example?

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen to be honest i have not since my code is working, all i need is to the script recognizes the sql file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check the file extension before deletion:

```
<?php
    foreach ($fids as $fid) {
        if (pathinfo($dire . '/' . $fid)['extension'] == 'sql') {
            unlink($dire . '/' . $fid); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Otherwise, you can scan your directory for only .sql with GLOB()

```
<?php
    $dire = 'my_dir';

    if (!empty($_POST['fid'])) {
        $fids = $_POST['fid'];
        foreach ($fids as $fid) {
            unlink($dire . '/' . $fid);
        }
    }
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
<?php
    $files = GLOB($dire . '/*{.sql}', GLOB_BRACE);
?>

<?php if ($files): ?>
    <?php foreach($files as $file): ?>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-dark table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="text-transform:uppercase;">
                    <td><small><?= basename($file); ?></small></td>
                    <td align="center"><small><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="fid[]" value="<?= basename($file); ?>"></small></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: that hit the Gold. Thank you so much, i did however a change on the code under the table view, placed the table right after <?php foreach($files as $file): ?> and now it is simply perfect, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So I guess you only want to list one file per table. Which is fine. Glad my script helps

Comment: Yes that is correct! Thank you so much, really thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I came across PHP's `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` some time ago. This built-in class will let you iterator through a directory and it's subdirectories and perform any action you want on the files in it.

Take a look at the example below on how to implement this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // The directory to remove files from
    $directory = $_POST['directory'];

    // The extension se are looking for
    $extension = $_POST['extension'];

    // Construct the iterator
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);

    // Loop through files
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
        if ($file->getExtension() == $extension) {
            echo 'Removing ' . $file . "\n";
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Implementation

You can replace your code with the following script. Note that I have used the `DirectoryIterator` in this case because you only want to iterate through a single directory.

```
<?php
/**
 * Directory overview
 */
// The directory to remove files from
$directory = '/path/to/directory';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    foreach ($_POST['fid'] as $filePath) {
        unlink $filePath;
    }
}
?>


<table class="table table-bordered table-dark table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>File</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $file): ?>
        <?php if ($file->isDot() || !$file->isFile()) continue; ?>
}        <tr style="text-transform:uppercase;">
            <td><small><?= $file; ?></small></td>
            <td align="center"><small><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="fid[]" value="<?= $file->getPathName(); ?>"></small></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Resources

- [DirectoryIterator - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: Thank you for your help on this PHP class script, I'm going to try to adapt that one, meanwhile if you can, is there any way to add this to my existing script? How can I do that?

Comment: @PedroCarvalho Take a look at the `Implementation` part of my answer.

Comment: Hi @Peter, it sure works just fine too. Your Implementation is great, thank you for your help. Wish you the best.